# Binding lambda to forwarding reference

Tags: c++, lambda, lifetime, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

Is it safe to bind to a lambda with `auto&&`? I.e will the lifetime of the lambda be extended to the lifetime of the forwarding reference? Why / why not?

```
auto&& fn = <lambda declaration>;
```

I suspect that it should be. As far as I understand, lambda expressions are supposed to be prvalue expressions, and the `auto&&` forwarding reference should then become an rvalue reference. rvalue references are supposed to extend the lifetime of temporaries, at least under certain conditions. But here I'm not quite sure if the lambda qualifies.

Comment: certainly seems to work: https://godbolt.org/z/GqfP64qnW

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes it compiles, but part of why I'm asking this is that I'm seeing ASAN failures around this pattern in certain cases, and I'm wondering if it's legal or not.

Comment: if you show a [mre] of the code causing problems we might be able to help

Answer (score 2):

Short answer. Yes and no.

No, it is not dangerous as you say.
Yes, it is safe to bind to a lambda with auto&&, and is **not dangerous**, because the temporary object isn't destroyed after the end of the definition statement. What happens is that the rvalue reference extends its lifetime (yes like you said) but only until the reference itself gets destroyed, when it is out of scope. So, you are right that it extends the lifetime, but does not do it in such a way that is dangerous.

To quote  Scott Meyers, as he elaborates in **Effective Modern C++**:

> The rules for type deduction of auto are the same as those of
> templates (apart from one exception: curly braces in auto are
> interpreted as std::initializer_lists).

Also, relating to this matter, declaring a lambda, which is always a pure function, with `auto&&` is a forwarding reference, thus it is an lvalue reference if initialized from an lvalue and an rvalue reference if initialized from an rvalue. Since lambdas are pure rvalue, it becomes an rvalue reference, which allows it to extend its lifetime but only until the reference itself gets destroyed, when it is out of scope.

Comment: Whether `auto&&` is deduced to a rvalue or lvalue reference doesn't matter for the lifetime extension. The rules are not dependent on the kind of reference.

Comment: Also, no idea what a "_pure lambda_" is.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, you are correct about that. Also, "pure lambda" is a typo. I was thinking about pure functions, and all lambdas are pure functions, thus there is no "pure lambda", you are right.

Comment: C++ lambdas are not any more or less pure than any other function.